# Implementing loop

Tags: android, handler

I need to implement a service which needs to periodically carry out a short task. I have used handler with sendmessagedelayed to implement loop. It works but is there a better way?

```
@Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message arg0) {
         //do something
         Message msgtx=Message.obtain();
         handler.sendMessageDelayed(msgtx, updaterate);
         return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the task is executed, say, each X minutes or more, using a handler is OK. If the delay between task executions is bigger (hours or so), I recommend using the `AlarmManager`:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long interval = XXX;// time in milisecs for the next execution
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, YourService.class);
i.setAction("some_action_to_indicate_the_task");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now + interval, pi);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this task to run even when your application is not running, using AlarmManager.
If you want it to run only when your application is running, best to use a handler.

Android doc says:

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.